# CSS Grid Layout Resize React

Tags: reactjs, css3, scss, grid

Не понимаю, как можно добиться такого поведения колонки, чтобы она заполняла все возможное место, забирая место пустой колонки. При этом чтобы была полная адаптивность, при изменение размеров

Я добился нужной мне адаптивности для широких экранов (все блоки идут одной строкой) (1 скрин)
И для мобильных (все блоки идут одним столбцом) (3 скрин)

Но как добиться того, чтобы блок расстягивался? (3 скрин)

При том, сколько блоков будет внутри, неизвестно, данные приходят с сервера и это массив

[image: Широкие экраны]

[image: Мобильные экраны]

[image: Средние экраны, суть вопроса]

[image: CSS Код контейнера]
[image: CSS Код карточки]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код

Comment: Добавил код компонентов

Comment: я правильно поняла, что Вы хотите, чтобы на больших экранах все блоки шли одной строкой, на маленьких экранах одним столбцом и на средних экранах (условно) чтобы 2 блока были на одной строке, а третий блок на второй строке, причем растягивался на всю ширину? т.е. по длине чтобы был как два верхних?